# Not getting most of my exit orders for short trades

Tags: pine-script

I am new to Pine but am a heavy user of ThinkScript and the UseThinkScript forum.

I have been writing this code for a couple years now and refining it along the way. I have been trying to convert it to PineScript from Thinkscript for the last 2-3 months. I took a few online courses and read tons of websites which got the code to where it is at now. This code backtest well on Thinkscript, to the tune of $20k+ per 6 months on TSLA and profitable on most other SP500 tickers. The problem I am having now is that I am not getting any close orders on my short trades which therefor affects my long trades since i am not pyramiding.

I have tried to comment out all long order (buy and close)
I have tried commenting out all my short close orders one by one
I have tried commenting out all all the variables one by one for the short entry orders
I have poured through the code many times to try to find a type.

Please just comment the correction vs fixing the error and re-posing my code.

Also, I will always take some friendly suggestions to improve the syntax or format of the code.

P.S. I had to remove some descriptive headers from my code or else it would be too long to post here.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © Mack_Dee_Sr

//@version=5
strategy(title              = "TEMPS", 
   overlay                  = true, 
   pyramiding               = 1, 
   calc_on_order_fills      = true, 
   calc_on_every_tick       = true, 
   default_qty_type         = strategy.percent_of_equity, 
   default_qty_value        = 100, 
   initial_capital          = 100000, 
   currency                 = currency.USD, 
   slippage                 = 8, 
   process_orders_on_close  = true, 
   close_entries_rule       = "ANY", 
   margin_long              = 100, 
   margin_short             = 100, 
   use_bar_magnifier        = true)

//SHORT ORDERS NOT WORKING
//Go Back and Look at Momentum to make sure ta.linreg is correct. Also double check the offset of 0
//Test Getting Rid of TSI Sell Signals?
//Find Out Why Some Orders Are Not Triggering When Buy or Hold Above/Below EMA Line Where Arrow Are At

ShowBuyTestingLabelEMA      = input(false)
ShowBuyTestingLabelTSI      = input(false)
ShowBuyTestingLabelMACD     = input(false)
ShowBuyTestingLabelPM       = input(false)
ShowSellTestingLabelEMA     = input(false)
ShowSellTestingLabelTSI     = input(false)
ShowSellTestingLabelMACD    = input(false)
ShowSellTestingLabelPM      = input(false)
ShowSellTestingLabelATR     = input(false)
ShowIndicators              = input(true)
ShowATR                     = input(false)
ShowOrders                  = input(true)
UseEMASeperation            = input(true)

TotalCapital                    = input(100000)                                         //Does Not Include Margin
MaximumPercentDailyDrawdown     = input(0.05)                                           //Based on Prop Firm Rules
LosingTradesBeforeFail          = input(5)                                              //Based on Individual Preference
MaxPercentDrawdownPerTrade      = input(0.03)                                           //Based on Individual Preference
RewardToRisk                    = input(2)                                              //Default R to R is 2:1

MaximumDrawdownDollarsPerDay    = TotalCapital * MaximumPercentDailyDrawdown            //Maximum Total Daily Dollar Loss Before Failure (ex. $5,000)
MaxDrawdownDollarsPerTrade      = MaximumDrawdownDollarsPerDay / LosingTradesBeforeFail //Maximum Dollar Loss per Trade Based on Individual Preference (ex $1,000)

DrawdownPerShare                = (close * MaxPercentDrawdownPerTrade)                  //Dollar Loss per Share at Defined Maximum Drawdown per Trade
MaxShares                       = MaxDrawdownDollarsPerTrade / DrawdownPerShare         //Dollar Loss per Trade / Drawdown per Share

//TABLE
PositionSize                    = table.new(
   position                     = position.bottom_left, 
   columns                      = 5, 
   rows                         = 2, 
   bgcolor                      = color.black, 
   border_width                 = 1, 
   frame_color                  = color.red, 
   frame_width                  = 2, 
   border_color                 = color.white)

table.cell(table_id = PositionSize, column = 0, row = 0, 
   text = "Max Shares", text_color = color.white, bgcolor = color.black)
table.cell(table_id = PositionSize, column = 1, row = 0, 
   text = "Long Stop", text_color = color.white, bgcolor = color.black)
table.cell(table_id = PositionSize, column = 2, row = 0, 
   text = "Long Take Profit", text_color = color.white, bgcolor = color.black)
table.cell(table_id = PositionSize, column = 3, row = 0, 
   text = "Short Stop", text_color = color.white, bgcolor = color.black)
table.cell(table_id = PositionSize, column = 4, row = 0, 
   text = "Short Take Profit", text_color = color.white, bgcolor = color.black)
table.cell(table_id = PositionSize, column = 0, row = 1, 
   text = str.tostring(math.round(MaxShares, 0)), tooltip = "test", text_color = color.white, bgcolor = color.black)
table.cell(table_id = PositionSize, column = 1, row = 1, 
   text = str.tostring(math.round((close - DrawdownPerShare), 2), "$#.##"), text_color = color.white, bgcolor = color.black)
table.cell(table_id = PositionSize, column = 2, row = 1, 
   text = str.tostring(math.round((close + (DrawdownPerShare * RewardToRisk)), 2), "$#.##"), text_color = color.white, bgcolor = color.black)
table.cell(table_id = PositionSize, column = 3, row = 1, 
   text = str.tostring(math.round((close + DrawdownPerShare), 2), "$#.##"), text_color = color.white, bgcolor = color.black)
table.cell(table_id = PositionSize, column = 4, row = 1, 
   text = str.tostring(math.round((close - (DrawdownPerShare * RewardToRisk)), 2), "$#.##"), text_color = color.white, bgcolor = color.black)

PreMarketHours                          = input.session("0700-0930:23456", "Pre-Market Hours")
DuringPreMarketHours(PreMarketHours)    => not na(time(timeframe.period, PreMarketHours))
DuringPreMarketHours2                   = DuringPreMarketHours(PreMarketHours) and timeframe.isintraday
PreMarketStart                          = DuringPreMarketHours2 and not DuringPreMarketHours2[1]

BuyTradingHours                         = input.session("1000-1500:23456", "Buy Trading Hours", tooltip = "Times To Recieve Buy Signals")
BuyDuringMarketHours(BuyTradingHours)   => not na(time(timeframe.period, BuyTradingHours))
BuyDuringMarketHours2                   = BuyDuringMarketHours(BuyTradingHours) and timeframe.isintraday

HoldTradingHours                        = input.session("1000-1540:23456", "Hold Trading Hours", tooltip = "Times To Recieve Hold Signals")
HoldDuringMarketHours(HoldTradingHours) => not na(time(timeframe.period, HoldTradingHours))
HoldDuringMarketHours2                  = HoldDuringMarketHours(HoldTradingHours) and timeframe.isintraday

LastCandle                              = input.session("1540-1600:23456", "Last Candles", tooltip = "Times To Close Positions")
FinalBar(LastCandle)                    => not na(time(timeframe.period, LastCandle))
FinalBar2                               = FinalBar(LastCandle) and timeframe.isintraday

EMA5        = (ta.ema(hl2, 5))
EMA12       = (ta.ema(hl2, 12))
EMA8        = (ta.ema(hl2, 8))
EMA9        = (ta.ema(hl2, 9))
EMA34       = (ta.ema(hl2, 34))
EMA50       = (ta.ema(hl2, 50))
EMA200      = (ta.ema(hl2, 200))

EMA5Line    = plot(EMA5,   color    = color.rgb(8, 227, 121),  title    = "5-EMA",      display     = display.pane)
EMA12Line   = plot(EMA12,  color    = color.rgb(214, 61, 241), title    = "12-EMA",     display     = display.pane)
EMA8Line    = plot(EMA8,   color    = color.rgb(8, 227, 121),  title    = "8-EMA",      display     = display.none)
EMA9Line    = plot(EMA9,   color    = color.rgb(214, 61, 241), title    = "9-EMA",      display     = display.none)
EMA34Line   = plot(EMA34,  color    = color.rgb(8, 227, 121),  title    = "34-EMA",     display     = display.none)
EMA50Line   = plot(EMA50,  color    = color.rgb(214, 61, 241), title    = "50-EMA",     display     = display.none)
EMA200Line  = plot(EMA200, color    = color.rgb(21, 130, 220), title    = "200-EMA",    display     = display.none)

Cloud1Color = EMA5  >= EMA12    ?     color.rgb(0, 129, 0, 55)      :     color.rgb(168, 0, 34, 25)
Cloud2Color = EMA8  >= EMA9     ?     color.rgb(76, 175, 80, 75)    :     color.rgb(244, 67, 54, 55)
Cloud3Color = EMA34 >= EMA50    ?     color.rgb(33, 243, 128, 75)   :     color.rgb(193, 12, 133, 55)

fill(EMA5Line,  EMA12Line, color    = Cloud1Color,               title    = "EMA Cloud 1", display    = display.all)
fill(EMA8Line,  EMA9Line,  color    = Cloud2Color,               title    = "EMA Cloud 2", display    = display.all)
fill(EMA34Line, EMA50Line, color    = Cloud3Color,               title    = "EMA Cloud 3", display    = display.all)

var EMASeperationThreshold      = 0.0

if timeframe.period             ==      "1"     and UseEMASeperation
    EMASeperationThreshold      :=      0.1
else if timeframe.period        ==      "5"     and UseEMASeperation
    EMASeperationThreshold      :=      0.2
else if timeframe.period        ==      "10"     and UseEMASeperation
    EMASeperationThreshold      :=      0.25
else if timeframe.period        ==      "15"     and UseEMASeperation
    EMASeperationThreshold      :=      0.25
else if timeframe.period        ==      "30"     and UseEMASeperation
    EMASeperationThreshold      :=      0.3
else if timeframe.period        ==      "60"     and UseEMASeperation
    EMASeperationThreshold      :=      0.3

//EMA BUY SIGNALS
EMABullish                      = EMA5 > EMA12
EMABearish                      = EMA5 < EMA12

EMAPercentSeperationBull        = ((EMA5/EMA12) * 100) - 100                //Distance Between EMA5 and EMA12
EMAPercentSeperationBullRound   = math.round(EMAPercentSeperationBull, 2)
EMAPercentSeperationBear        = ((EMA12/EMA5) * 100) - 100                //Distance Between EMA12 and EMA5
EMAPercentSeperationBearRound   = math.round(EMAPercentSeperationBear, 2)

EMAPercentBullish               = (EMAPercentSeperationBullRound >= EMASeperationThreshold) and EMABullish //EMA Seperation Greater than threshold and EMA Trending Up
EMAPercentBearish               = (EMAPercentSeperationBearRound >= EMASeperationThreshold) and EMABearish //EMA Seperation Greater than threshold and EMA Trending Down
plotshape(ShowBuyTestingLabelEMA and EMAPercentBullish,    style = shape.cross, location = location.top,      color = color.rgb(63, 255, 56), text = "%Bu")
plotshape(ShowBuyTestingLabelEMA and EMAPercentBearish,    style = shape.cross, location = location.bottom,   color = color.rgb(63, 255, 56), text = "%Be")

//EMA SELL SIGNALS
EMALongClose                    = ta.crossunder(EMA5, EMA12) or (EMABullish and (EMAPercentSeperationBullRound <= EMASeperationThreshold))
EMAShortClose                   = ta.crossover(EMA5, EMA12) or (EMABearish and (EMAPercentSeperationBearRound <= EMASeperationThreshold))
plotshape(ShowSellTestingLabelEMA and EMALongClose,        style = shape.xcross, location = location.top,      color = color.rgb(255, 56, 56), text = "ELC")
plotshape(ShowSellTestingLabelEMA and EMAShortClose,       style = shape.xcross, location = location.bottom,   color = color.rgb(255, 56, 56), text = "ESC")

EMA5D           = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", ta.ema(hl2, 5))
EMA12D          = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", ta.ema(hl2, 12))
EMA34D          = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", ta.ema(hl2, 34))
EMA50D          = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", ta.ema(hl2, 50))
EMA200D         = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", ta.ema(hl2, 200))

EMA5DLine       = plot(EMA5D,   color = color.rgb(7, 131, 11, 75),  title = "5D-EMA-Line",      display = display.none)
EMA12DLine      = plot(EMA12D,  color = color.rgb(7, 131, 11, 75),  title = "12D-EMA-Line",     display = display.none)
EMA34DLine      = plot(EMA34D,  color = color.rgb(192, 21, 21, 75), title = "34D-EMA-Line",     display = display.none)
EMA50DLine      = plot(EMA50D,  color = color.rgb(192, 21, 21, 75), title = "50D-EMA-Line",     display = display.none)
EMA200DLine     = plot(EMA200D, color = color.rgb(38, 55, 153, 75), title = "200D-EMA-Line",    display = display.none)

TSIDiff                 = close-close[1]
DoubleSmoothAbsDiff     = ta.ema(ta.ema(math.abs(TSIDiff), 25), 13)
TSIValue                = 100 * ((ta.ema(ta.ema(TSIDiff, 25), 13)) / (DoubleSmoothAbsDiff))
TSIRound                = math.round(TSIValue, 2)

//TSI BUY SIGNAL
TSIBull                 = (TSIRound >= TSIRound[1]) or (TSIRound >= TSIRound[2]) //TSI Greater Than or Equal to 1 or 2 Bars Before
TSIBear                 = (TSIRound <= TSIRound[1]) or (TSIRound <= TSIRound[2]) //TSI Less Than or Equal to 1 or 2 Bars Before
plotshape(ShowBuyTestingLabelTSI and TSIBull,          style = shape.cross, location = location.top,      color = color.rgb(63, 255, 56), text = "TSI")
plotshape(ShowBuyTestingLabelTSI and TSIBear,          style = shape.cross, location = location.bottom,   color = color.rgb(63, 255, 56), text = "TSI")

//TSI SELL SIGNAL
TSILongClose            = TSIRound < (TSIRound[1] * 0.975)
TSIShortClose           = TSIRound > (TSIRound[1] * 1.025)
plotshape(ShowSellTestingLabelTSI and TSILongClose,    style = shape.xcross, location = location.top,      color = color.rgb(255, 56, 56), text = "TLC")
plotshape(ShowSellTestingLabelTSI and TSIShortClose,   style = shape.xcross, location = location.bottom,   color = color.rgb(255, 56, 56), text = "TSC")

MACDValue               = ta.ema(close, 10) - ta.ema(close, 22)
MACDAverage             = ta.ema(MACDValue, 8)
MACDDiff                = MACDValue - MACDAverage

//MACD BUY SIGNAL
MACDBull                = TSIRound >= MACDAverage
MACDBear                = TSIRound <= MACDAverage
plotshape(ShowBuyTestingLabelMACD and MACDBull,          style = shape.cross, location = location.top,      color = color.rgb(63, 255, 56), text = "MBu")
plotshape(ShowBuyTestingLabelMACD and MACDBear,          style = shape.cross, location = location.bottom,   color = color.rgb(63, 255, 56), text = "MBe")

//MACD SELL SIGNAL
TSIMACDLongClose        = ta.crossunder(TSIRound, MACDAverage)
TSIMACDShortClose       = ta.crossover(TSIRound, MACDAverage)
plotshape(ShowSellTestingLabelMACD and TSIMACDLongClose,  style = shape.xcross, location = location.top,      color = color.rgb(255, 56, 56), text = "MLC")
plotshape(ShowSellTestingLabelMACD and TSIMACDShortClose, style = shape.xcross, location = location.bottom,   color = color.rgb(255, 56, 56), text = "MSC")

//SQUEEZE PRO
SqueezeLength           = 20
BBMultiply              = 2.0
KeltnerLow              = 2.0

//BOLLINGER BANDS
BollingerBand           = ta.sma(close, SqueezeLength)
BBDeviation             = BBMultiply * (ta.stdev(close, SqueezeLength))
BollingerUpper          = BollingerBand + BBDeviation
BollingerLower          = BollingerBand - BBDeviation

//KELTNER CHANNELS
TrueRange               = ta.atr(1) //or TrueRange = math.max((high - low), math.abs(high - close[1]), math.abs(low - close[1]))
KeltnerBasis            = ta.sma(close, SqueezeLength)
KCDeviation             = ta.sma(TrueRange, SqueezeLength)
KeltnerUpperLow         = KeltnerBasis + (KCDeviation * KeltnerLow)
KeltnerLowerLow         = KeltnerBasis - (KCDeviation * KeltnerLow)

//SQUEEZE CONDITIONS
NoSqz                   = (BollingerLower < KeltnerLowerLow) or (BollingerUpper > KeltnerUpperLow)

//MOMENTUM OSCILLATOR
HighestHigh             = math.max(high, SqueezeLength)
LowestLow               = math.min(low, SqueezeLength)
Average                 = (HighestHigh + LowestLow) / 2
AverageSMA              = (Average + KeltnerBasis) / 2
Momentum                = ta.linreg(close - AverageSMA, SqueezeLength, 0)

//SQUEEZE BUY SIGNAL
SqueezeBull             = (Momentum > 0) and (Momentum > Momentum[1])
SqueezeBear             = (Momentum > 0) and (Momentum < Momentum[1])

//SQUEEZE SELL SIGNAL
SqueezeSellLong         = (Momentum < Momentum[1]) and (Momentum[1] < Momentum[2]) and (Momentum [2] < Momentum[3])
SqueezeSellShort        = (Momentum > Momentum[1]) and (Momentum[1] > Momentum[2]) and (Momentum [2] > Momentum[3])

var PreMarketHighPrice  = 0.0
var PreMarketLowPrice   = 0.0

if PreMarketStart
    PreMarketHighPrice  := high
    PreMarketLowPrice   := low
else if DuringPreMarketHours2
    PreMarketHighPrice  := math.max(PreMarketHighPrice, high)
    PreMarketLowPrice   := math.min(PreMarketLowPrice, low)

PreMarketHighLine       = plot(timeframe.isintraday     ?   PreMarketHighPrice  :  na,  title     = "PreMarket High", 
   color =  color.rgb(160, 160, 160, 98), linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_circles,  display   = display.all)
PreMarketLowLine        = plot(timeframe.isintraday     ?   PreMarketLowPrice   :   na, title     = "PreMarket Low", 
   color =  color.rgb(160, 160, 160, 98), linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_circles,  display   = display.all)
fill(PreMarketHighLine, PreMarketLowLine, color = color.rgb(160, 160, 160, 85),       title     = "PreMarket High/Low Cloud", 
   display = display.all)

//PREMARKET HIGH/LOW BUY SIGNAL
PreMarketLong           = low > PreMarketHighPrice
PreMarketShort          = high < PreMarketLowPrice
plotshape(ShowBuyTestingLabelPM and PreMarketLong,           style = shape.cross, location = location.top,      color = color.rgb(63, 255, 56), text = "PM")
plotshape(ShowBuyTestingLabelPM and PreMarketShort,          style = shape.cross, location = location.bottom,   color = color.rgb(63, 255, 56), text = "PM")

//PREMARKET HIGH/LOW SELL SIGNALS
PreMarketLongClose      = PreMarketLong[1] and (close < PreMarketHighPrice)
PreMarketShortClose     = PreMarketShort[1] and (close > PreMarketLowPrice)
plotshape(ShowSellTestingLabelPM and PreMarketLongClose,     style = shape.xcross, location = location.top,      color = color.rgb(255, 56, 56), text = "PMLC")
plotshape(ShowSellTestingLabelPM and PreMarketShortClose,    style = shape.xcross, location = location.bottom,   color = color.rgb(255, 56, 56), text = "PMSC")

YesterdayHigh           = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", high[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
YesterdayLow            = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", low[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

YesterdayHighLine       = plot(timeframe.isintraday     ?   YesterdayHigh   :   na,     title = "Yesterday High", 
   color = color.rgb(44, 159, 48), linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_cross, display = display.pane)
YesterdayLowLine        = plot(timeframe.isintraday     ?   YesterdayLow    :   na,     title = "Yesterday Low", 
   color = color.rgb(159, 44, 44), linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_cross, display = display.pane)
fill(YesterdayHighLine, YesterdayLowLine, color = color.rgb(28, 219, 34, 90), title = "Yesterday High/Low Cloud", 
   display = display.none)

LongBuyInd              = BuyDuringMarketHours2 and PreMarketLong and EMAPercentBullish and TSIBull and MACDBull and SqueezeBull
ShortBuyInd             = BuyDuringMarketHours2 and PreMarketShort and EMAPercentBearish and TSIBear and MACDBear and SqueezeBear

LongHoldInd             = HoldDuringMarketHours2 and PreMarketLong and EMAPercentBullish
ShortHoldInd            = HoldDuringMarketHours2 and PreMarketShort and EMAPercentBearish

LongEntryInd            = (LongBuyInd or LongHoldInd) and (LongBuyInd[1] or LongBuyInd[2]) and (low <= (EMA5 * 1.0025))
ShortEntryInd           = (ShortBuyInd or ShortHoldInd) and (ShortBuyInd[1] or ShortBuyInd[2]) and (high >= (EMA5 * 0.9975))

CloseLessOpen               = close < open
CloseMoreOpen               = close > open
CloseLessEMA5               = close < EMA5
CloseMoreEMA5               = close > EMA5

LongPriceActClose           = CloseLessOpen and CloseLessEMA5 and (EMALongClose or TSILongClose or TSIMACDLongClose or PreMarketLongClose) and 
                              (LongBuyInd[1] or LongHoldInd[1])        //Exit on Close Signals
ShortPriceActClose          = CloseMoreOpen and CloseMoreEMA5 and (EMAShortClose or TSIShortClose or TSIMACDShortClose or PreMarketShortClose) and 
                              (ShortBuyInd[1] or ShortHoldInd[1])      //Exit on CLose Signals

LongEntryLine        = EMA5 * 1.0025
ShortEntryLine       = EMA5 * 0.9975
LongEntryLine2       = nz(LongEntryLine[1], LongEntryLine)
ShortEntryLine2      = nz(ShortEntryLine[1], ShortEntryLine)

if close[1] > LongEntryLine2
    LongEntryLine    := math.max(LongEntryLine, LongEntryLine2)
    LongEntryLine
if close[1] < ShortEntryLine2
    ShortEntryLine   := math.min(ShortEntryLine, ShortEntryLine2)
    ShortEntryLine

LongEntryPlot    = plot(LongBuyInd or LongHoldInd       ?   LongEntryLine    :   na,  style=plot.style_linebr, 
   linewidth=3, color = color.black,   display = display.pane)
ShortEntryPlot   = plot(ShortBuyInd or ShortHoldInd     ?   ShortEntryLine   :   na,  style=plot.style_linebr, 
   linewidth=3, color = color.black,  display = display.pane)

LongBelowEntry = low <= LongEntryLine
ShortAboveEntry = high >= ShortEntryLine

ATR                 = ta.atr(14)
ATRMultiplier       = 1.6

LongStopLoss        = hl2 - ATRMultiplier * ATR
ShortStopLoss       = hl2 + ATRMultiplier * ATR
LongStopLoss2       = nz(LongStopLoss[1], LongStopLoss)
ShortStopLoss2      = nz(ShortStopLoss[1], ShortStopLoss)

if close[1] > LongStopLoss2
    LongStopLoss    := math.max(LongStopLoss, LongStopLoss2)
    LongStopLoss
if close[1] < ShortStopLoss2
    ShortStopLoss   := math.min(ShortStopLoss, ShortStopLoss2)
    ShortStopLoss

LongStopLossPlot    = plot(ShowATR and (LongBuyInd or LongHoldInd)      ?   LongStopLoss    :   na,     title = 
   "Long Trend", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=5, color = color.rgb(17, 255, 0),   display = display.pane)
ShortStopLossPlot   = plot(ShowATR and (ShortBuyInd or ShortHoldInd)    ?   ShortStopLoss   :   na,     title = 
   "Down Trend", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=5, color = color.rgb(255, 59, 59),  display = display.pane)

//ATR SELL SIGNAL
ATRLongClose        = ta.crossunder(low, LongStopLoss) //(LongBuyInd or LongHoldInd) and 
ATRShortClose       = ta.crossover(high, ShortStopLoss) //(ShortBuyInd or ShortHoldInd) and 
plotshape(ShowSellTestingLabelATR and ATRLongClose,    style = shape.xcross, location = location.top,      color = color.rgb(255, 56, 56), text = "ATRLC")
plotshape(ShowSellTestingLabelATR and ATRShortClose,   style = shape.xcross, location = location.bottom,   color = color.rgb(255, 56, 56), text = "ATRSC")

LowLowSell                  = low < math.min(low[1], low[2], low[3], low[4])
HighHighSell                = high > math.max(high[1], high[2], high[3], high[4])
LowLessEMA12                = low < EMA12
HighMoreEMA12               = high > EMA12
LongTakeProfit              = high > (EMA5 * 1.01)
ShortTakeProfit             = low < (EMA5 * 0.99)
//ATRLongClose
//ATRShortClose

LongHardClose               = (LowLowSell or LowLessEMA12 or LongTakeProfit or ATRLongClose or FinalBar2) and 
                              (LongBuyInd[1] or LongHoldInd[1])
ShortHardClose              = (HighHighSell or HighMoreEMA12 or ShortTakeProfit or ATRShortClose or FinalBar2) and
                              (ShortBuyInd[1] or ShortHoldInd[1])

BColor          =   color.rgb(124, 124, 124)

if LongBuyInd
    BColor      :=  color.rgb(29, 225, 36)
else if ShortBuyInd
    BColor      :=  color.rgb(236, 17, 17)
else if  LongHoldInd
    BColor      :=  color.rgb(32, 123, 35)
else if  ShortHoldInd
    BColor      :=  color.rgb(147, 27, 27)
    BColor

barcolor(BColor)
plotcandle(open, high, low, close, title = "Candle Colors", 
   color = BColor, wickcolor = BColor, bordercolor = BColor, display = display.pane)

//SELL
LongSellBub     = LongPriceActClose or LongHardClose //and (LongEntryInd[1] or LongHoldInd2[1]) and (LongEntryInd[2] or LongHoldInd2[2])
ShortSellBub    = ShortPriceActClose or ShortHardClose //and (ShortEntryInd[1] or ShortHoldInd2[1]) and (ShortEntryInd[2] or ShortHoldInd2[2])
plotshape(ShowIndicators and LongSellBub,   style = shape.xcross,       location = location.abovebar,    color = color.red,      size = size.tiny)
plotshape(ShowIndicators and ShortSellBub,  style = shape.xcross,       location = location.belowbar,    color = color.red,      size = size.tiny)

//BUY
LongBuyBub      = (LongBuyInd or LongHoldInd) and LongBelowEntry and not LongPriceActClose and not LongHardClose
ShortBuyBub     = (ShortBuyInd or ShortHoldInd) and ShortAboveEntry and not ShortPriceActClose and not ShortHardClose
plotshape(ShowIndicators and LongBuyBub,    style = shape.triangleup,   location = location.belowbar,    color = color.black,    size = size.tiny)
plotshape(ShowIndicators and ShortBuyBub,   style = shape.triangledown, location = location.abovebar,    color = color.black,    size = size.tiny)

//TAKE PROFIT
LongTkPftBub    = (LongEntryInd or LongHoldInd) and LongTakeProfit
ShortTkPftBub   = (ShortEntryInd or ShortHoldInd) and ShortTakeProfit
plotshape(ShowIndicators and LongTkPftBub,  style = shape.circle,       location = location.abovebar,    color = color.purple,   size = size.tiny)
plotshape(ShowIndicators and ShortTkPftBub, style = shape.circle,       location = location.belowbar,    color = color.purple,   size = size.tiny)

//FINAL BAR
plotshape(ShowIndicators and FinalBar2,     style = shape.diamond,      location = location.abovebar,    color = color.maroon,   size = size.tiny)

//LONG BUY ORDERS
if ShowOrders and LongBuyInd and not LongPriceActClose and not LongHardClose and ta.cross(close, LongEntryLine)
    strategy.entry("TEMPS LONG", strategy.long, qty = MaxShares, limit = LongEntryLine, comment = "Long")

//LONG CLOSE ORDERS
if ShowOrders and ATRLongClose and strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit("ATR LONG", "TEMPS LONG", stop = LongStopLoss, comment = "ATR")
if ShowOrders and PreMarketLongClose and strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit("PM LONG", "TEMPS LONG", stop = close, comment = "PM")
if ShowOrders and FinalBar2 and strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit("FINAL LONG", "TEMPS LONG", stop = close, comment = "FINAL")
if ShowOrders and LowLessEMA12 and strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit("EMA12 LONG", "TEMPS LONG", stop = EMA12, comment = "EMA12")
if ShowOrders and LowLowSell and strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit("LOW4 LONG", "TEMPS LONG", stop = math.min(low[1], low[2], low[3], low[4]), comment = "LOW4")
if ShowOrders and LongTakeProfit and strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit("PFT LONG", "TEMPS LONG", stop = (EMA5 * 1.01), comment = "PFT")
if ShowOrders and LongPriceActClose and strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit("CLOSE LONG", "TEMPS LONG", stop = close, comment = "REG")

//SHORT BUY ORDERS
if ShowOrders and ShortBuyInd and not ShortPriceActClose and not ShortHardClose and ta.cross(close, ShortEntryLine)
    strategy.entry("TEMPS SHORT", strategy.short, qty = MaxShares, limit = ShortEntryLine, comment = "Short")

//SHORT CLOSE ORDERS
if ShowOrders and ATRShortClose and strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit("ATR SHORT", "TEMPS SHORT", stop = ShortStopLoss, comment = "ATR")
if ShowOrders and PreMarketShortClose and strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit("PM SHORT", "TEMPS SHORT", stop = close, comment = "PM")
if ShowOrders and FinalBar2 and strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit("FINAL SHORT", "TEMPS SHORT", stop = close, comment = "FINAL")
if ShowOrders and HighMoreEMA12 and strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit("EMA12 SHORT", "TEMPS SHORT", stop = EMA12, comment = "EMA12")
if ShowOrders and HighHighSell and strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit("LOW4 SHORT", "TEMPS SHORT", stop = math.max(high[1], high[2], high[3], high[4]), comment = "LOW4")
if ShowOrders and ShortTakeProfit and strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit("PFT SHORT", "TEMPS SHORT", stop = (EMA5 * 0.99), comment = "PFT")
if ShowOrders and ShortPriceActClose and strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit("CLOSE SHORT", "TEMPS SHORT", stop = close, comment = "REG")
```

Comment: I figured it out. I had "strategy.position_size > 0" added to all my exit orders. I didn't realize that it must be "< 0" to recognize an active short order thus none of my exit orders saw that I was currently in a short trade and didn't trigger.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).